# Can I run Google Maps API without internet access using OpenStreet Tiles?

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

Is it permitted to use the Google Maps API (ver 2) in offline mode if I use OpenStreet tiles?

If so, how can I do this?   I can store the Google JS file locally (main.js).  What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not permitted according to the Terms Of Service

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

It is also unlikely to work, as the API Javascript is designed only to work online e.g. it must be able to talk to Googles servers.